# register login error include passport

Tags: node.js, passport.js

So I'm looking to implement passport and I'm running into an include issue.

Here is what I have so far:

users_controller.js

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('../models/user');

exports.register = function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register', { title: 'Rafflefly | Register' });
}

exports.post_register = function(req, res, next) {
  var first_name = req.body.first_name;
  var last_name = req.body.last_name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;

  // validations
  req.checkBody('first name', 'The first name is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('last name', 'The last name is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'An account email is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'This account email is not valid').isEmail();
  req.checkBody('password', 'An account password is required').notEmpty();

  if (error) {
    req.flash('error', 'The form could not send successfully');
  } else {
    var newUser = new User({
      first_name: first_name,
      last_name: last_name,
      email: email,
      password: password,
    });

    nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
      // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          host: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
          port: 587,
          auth: {
            user: process.env.SENDGRID_USERNAME,
            pass: process.env.SENDGRID_PASSWORD,
          }
        });
      } else {
        transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
          port: 587,
          auth: {
            user: 'qkkvnabtziufbksa@ethereal.email',
            pass: 'A4W9HF2WbhAav263VM',
          }
        });
      }
      // setup email data with unicode symbols
      let mailOptions = {
        from: process.env.GLOBAL_EMAIL || 'ben@benbagley.co.uk', // sender address
        to: `${email}`, // list of receivers
        subject: 'Welcome to Rafflefly', // Subject line
        html: `Welcome to Rafflefly` // html body
      };
      // send mail with defined transport object
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
          return console.log(error);
        }

        req.flash('success', 'You are now registered, you can now login!');
        res.redirect('/');
      });
    });

    User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user) {
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(user);
    });
  }
};

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
    },
    function(email, password, done) {
      User.getUserByEmail(email, function(err, user){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!user){
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown Email Address'});
        }

        User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
          if(err) throw err;
          if(isMatch){
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
          }
        });
      });
    }));

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });

exports.login = function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login', { title: 'Rafflefly | Login' });
}

exports.post_login = function(req, res, next) {
  res.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/dashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true })
  );
}
```

layout.pug

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    meta(charset='utf-8')

    link(rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/output.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css')
  body(class='antialiased min-h-screen')
    include navigation
    include error
    block content
    include footer

    script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/fontawesome-all.min.js' defer)
    script(src='/javascripts/site.js')
```

Here is my file structure

[image]

So all other pages are working here, but when I go to submit the registration form, I get the error, the register page does load but this error only seems to be happening in post when submitting the form.

The error I am getting is

```
[nodemon] 1.15.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
Connection has been established
Mongoose: users.ensureIndex({ email: 1 }, { unique: true, background: true })
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "/Users/benbagley/Code/rafflefly/views"
    at Function.render (/Users/benbagley/Code/rafflefly/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/benbagley/Code/rafflefly/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:971:7)
    at /Users/benbagley/Code/rafflefly/app.js:88:7
    at Layer.handle_error (/Users/benbagley/Code/rafflefly/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/benbagley/Code/rafflefly/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
    at /Users/benbagley/Code/rafflefly/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/benbagley/Code/rafflefly/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)

    at next (/Users/benbagley/Code/rafflefly/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Layer.handle_error (/Users/benbagley/Code/rafflefly/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:67:12)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/benbagley/Code/rafflefly/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
    at /Users/benbagley/Code/rafflefly/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/benbagley/Code/rafflefly/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/benbagley/Code/rafflefly/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Layer.handle_error (/Users/benbagley/Code/rafflefly/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:67:12)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/benbagley/Code/rafflefly/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
    at /Users/benbagley/Code/rafflefly/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
POST /register 500 248.111 ms - 2006
```

Any help here is appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var passport = require('passport');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var sslRedirect = require('heroku-ssl-redirect');

var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

mongoose.set('debug', true); // Only set when debugging

// enable ssl redirect
app.use(sslRedirect());

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// expressSession
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true
}));

// Connect Flash
app.use(flash());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
  res.locals.errors = req.flash('error');
  next();
});

app.use('/', index);

// passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Database connection
if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
} else {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/rafflefly');
}

var db = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log("Connection has been established");
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error'); // line 88
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Does `app.js` render a view on line 88? Especially a view called `'error'`? That would possibly explain the error. Can you include line 88 and a few surrounding lines for reference? (I don't think the whole `app.js` file is relevant)

Comment: @ContinuousLoad adding app.js, please see edit 1. I have highlighted where line 88 is.

Comment: Thanks. The `error.pug` view is in the `shared` subdirectory, so in order for `render()` to find it, you would need `res.render('shared/error.pug)`. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `res.render('shared/error.pug)` as mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/users/8436941/continuousload